# SAS date format (mmddyy10.) displays as ddmm1958 in excel pivot

Tags: excel, sas

i have a data_dt field with informat mmddyyyy10. where the values are 14MAY2018 and 31MAY2018. After I refresh my excel pivot table  (sas add in), they show 30May1958 and 13May1958.  Doing a proc content shows the informat of the field. How should I fix this to reflect correct value ?

```
DATA_DT (SAS)
14MAY2018
31MAY2018

DATA_DT (EXCEL)
30May1958
13May1958

Alphabetic List of Variables and Attributes                     
#   Variable    Type    Len     Format  Informat    Label
1   DATA_DT     Num     8       DATE9.  MMDDYY10.   DATA_DT
```

Answer (score 3):

SAS date indices start 1/1/1960, your Excel 1/1/1900 - difference 21915 days (difference between `14MAY2018` and `13May1958`). A common solution in a situation like this is to convert to Text before export. Or add `21916` to all imported dates.

Comment: thanks, my issue is when i export to xlsx, the field shows the correct format i.e. same as SAS. But if I do a refresh data via SAS add in to pivot table, I can see that the field becomes a number that's adhering to the excel format i.e. 1958 era ..

Comment: You could change the sheet to have an unformatted, hidden column `SAS Date Number` and a visible, formatted and used in pivot table column `Excel Date` whose cell values are `=SAS Date + 21915`

Comment: This sounds like a defect in the SAS/Excel add-in because it is not consistent with the SAS export to Excel. You might want to report it to SAS tech support.

Comment: yes. i just raised a ticket as i don't believe that i need to subtract or add the sas format value to excel given that exporting has no issue